# Add library root dependency for a Gradle project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a file in `src/main/conf` that I wanna read from my source code.
Currently I manually add the directory in the Dependencies section in 
`"Project Structure/Modules/Dependencies"`, and the conf directory gets a tag `"library root"`.

But everytime gradle builds, this has to be repeated. How do I this within gradle automatically.

New to gradle. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean like a text file you want to read, or a library you want to add a dependency on?

Comment: Looking to read a text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt user here, so not very fluent in Gradle, but have you tried adding the directory to the resources srcDirs? As in

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources', 'src/main/conf']
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:working_with_java_source_sets

Comment: A better way would be to add `src/main/conf` to the existing resource dirs rather than overriding it completely